# Mass Linter submissions - (Like button related) - How to

Tags: java, javascript, html, facebook-like

We operate a website with thousands of new content per month and use the Like button with OG tags.

However, very often the Like button does not work properly for content that was not refreshed by FB. As a FB admin on the site, I can manually paste the urls one by one in the Linter tool here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug but what would be the best way of making this process more automatic ? (Create a links page pointing to Linter with appended urls and then click on those one by one, RSS, submission engine, ... ?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This page does not require authentication so you could write a script that mass submits them via cURL or wget one by one via this url: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://example.com

Answer (score 0):

The solution such a [Rss Feed facebook Linter](http://social.brainhungry.com/facebook-mass-url-linter/) might help.

It debugs all URLs in Feed.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a [Facebook mass url debugger](http://social.brainhungry.com/facebook-mass-url-linter/)

that reads the RSS feed of a website and lints them.